# How Tableau Extract connection works in Tableau desktop?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to know more about Extract connection in Tableau Desktop

Let's say the data source that I connect from Tableau desktop is SQL Server. Assume that I selected Extract connection.

I would like to know what happens in background if I select extract connection?

Where is it exactly the extracted dataset gets stored?

Is it stored in RAM memory of the machine in which the Tableau desktop is installed? If yes, then what happens if the extracted dataset size is more than RAM memory size?

Or

Does it get stored in some cache memory of Tableau desktop software itself?

Comment: Check out a wonderfully detailed blog entry on Tableau's site at http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2014/7/understanding-tableau-data-extracts-part1. The author goes into more detail than we could provide here on SO.

Comment: Yes.. That article you have shared is really  nice.. Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select extract in tableau it will ask the location where the offline (extracted) data will be saved. It will save in your hard disk in (.tde) or (.twbx).

**Tableau not storing extracted data in RAM**